# Plug and Play Java EE Application

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, wildfly

I Wanted to create Java EE application in JSF+Spring Framework with WildFly AS. One of the hot requirements is:
 **Plug and Play Modules** This means if I update my application Or Add new module into my Application.
**(Obviously Update bean.xml, web.xml, pojo classes , jars etc)**
Then without redeployment of my *.war file and with out restarting my Wildfly AS changes occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a complicated requirement for a few reasons. How will you handle changes to your DB schema/entity model? How will you handle sessions which are in progress at the time of the upgrade and are actively using the 'old' code? How do you handle changes to container managed code, code that is managed by the container only at deployment time, for example new EJBs etc?

One approach I have seen used in production to achieve some of these requirements is to do rolling updates with application versioning and full schema backwards compatibility. This is done in a clustered environment which is fronted by proxy servers that can allow active sessions using the old version of the application to continue until finished and ensure that new sessions go to servers/contexts containing the new version of the code. So you end up still deploying WARs which contain the new version of your code, and eventually undeploy the old versions when all old sessions have ended/expired. To do this you have to assume the burden in your code to fully support working against two simultaneous versions of your model when new versions introduce changes to it. This is not a trivial burden. You also have to assume the burden of the extra infrastructure to route sessions appropriately.

I know a product like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) will let you do hot deploys of code (even things like EJBs) with the idea being that it shortens the develop/test cycle but I haven't seen it used outside of a development environment. Also you would still have to deal with active sessions that were started on the old version /model.